# How to solve an encoding issue using nohup python?

Tags: python, bash, nohup

I try to run a python 3.6 script in nohup :

```
! export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8  && echo  $PYTHONIOENCODING  && nohup  python -u myscript.py train    > zoutput.txt  &
```

it works well as follow
( ***no error and correct output is generated*** ) :
It means the script has no syntax error.

```
! export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8  && echo  $PYTHONIOENCODING  && nohup  python -u myscript.py train    > zoutput.txt
```

But, failed when adding &

```
! export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8  && echo  $PYTHONIOENCODING  && nohup  python -u myscript.py train    > zoutput.txt  &
```

saying syntax in the python script !!! on quote :

```
# pylint: disable=C0321,C0103,E1221,C0301,E1305,E1121,C0302,C0330
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

#### Code

    m['preprocess'] = dir_data + f'/input/{data_name}/train/'
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How to handle character encoding issue ?

Comment: can you add a bit more of the python script? It looks like this is invalid syntax, nothing to do with encoding

Comment: what's your python version, f-strings new to 3.6

Comment: It;s python 3.6, as mentionned the script is working fine without &

Comment: I see `!` at the beginning - do you run it in `Jupyter` ?

Comment: `invalid syntax` doesn't mean wrong encoding - you could accidently delete `)` in previous line and then it gives `invalid syntax`. First check what you have in previous line.

Comment: the script is running FINE without &  at end of command line.
So, the python script is correct.

This is an encoding issue.

Comment: I don't see how one follows from the other. Again, could you clarify whether this is in Jupyter or some other environment?

Comment: Just check carefully the command lines, there are different... you can try on your side too